# What is the probability the first $n$ rolls of a die sum to 6?

Tags: combinatorics

If I repeatedly toss a $6$-sided die, what is the probability that the first $n$ rolls sum to $6$ for any $n$?

For this I only need to consider $n$, number of tosses,  [1-6].  You can only throw at most 6 times.

So I'm trying to set this up using Bose-Einstein theorem $\left(\binom{n+k-1}{k}\right)$ because we have the equation $(x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 6)$ as the the solution for $n$ tosses $\leq 6$.

For $n=1$, $x_1 = 6$, only has 1 possibility.

For $n=2$, $x_1 + x_2 = 6$,  has the set $(3,3), (2,4), (4,2), (5,1), (1,5)$ with $5$ possibilities.

For $n=3$, we have $(2,2,2), (1,2,3)$ which can be thrown $3!$ ways, and $(1,1,4)$ which has $3$ ways total of $10$ ways for $n=3$.

Then for $n=4$ we have $(2,2,1,1)$ which can be ordered $6$ ways, and $(3,1,1,1)$ which is $4$ ways to be thrown, for $10$ combos.

$n=5$ only has the sequence $(1,1,1,1,2)$ which can be ordered $5$ ways.

and $n=6$ has only $(1,1,1,1,1,1)$ only $1$ way.

Then the numerator should sum all these possibilities, and the denominator should be the total number of tosses $6+6^2+6^3+ \ldots + 6^6$ total combinations.

Is this on the right track?

but this is cumbersome to "do by hand".

Answer (score 3):

I think it is easiest to work recursively.  Let $p_i$ be the probability that your string sums to $i$ at some point.  Then of course $p_1=\frac 16$.  Considering the final toss, we see that $$p_2=\frac 16+\frac 16\times p_1\quad \&\quad p_3=\frac 16+\frac 16p_1+\frac 16p_2$$

Continuing in this spirit we see that, for $1≤i≤6$ $$p_i=\frac 16+\frac 16\times\sum_{j<i}p_j$$

This quickly shows that $\boxed{p_6=.36023234}$

Worth noting: for $i>6$ we have $$p_i=\frac 16\times \sum_{j=i-6}^{i-1}p_j$$ though you don't need that for this problem.  You can use this formula for all the $p_i$ if you like, just set $p_0=1$ (and $p_i=0$ for $i<0$).

Comment: Nice, thanks for helping anyway.